# Example of how to use functions to keep code clean

Tags: php, laravel

I have code that requires a lot of repeated code such as try and catch exceptions. Looking at the code below could I put the try and catch exception into a function to keep it clean?

```
public function home(){

 try{
        $variable     = DB::table($tableone)->first();
         }catch(\Exception $e){
 }

//some code
 try {
        $variabletwo   = DB::table($tabletwo)->first();
         }catch(\Exception $e){
 }
//some code
 try {
        $variablethree    = DB::table($tablethree)->first();   
        }catch(\Exception $e){
     }

}
```

Comment: is there any problem, when writing the whole operations in one try block ?

Comment: no there is no problem in writing this in one try block however I do have examples code where there is code in-between the queries .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function GetFirst($tbl) {
    try
    {
        return DB::table($tbl)->first();
    }
    catch (Exception $e) 
    { ... }
}

$variableone = GetFirst($tableone);
$variabletwo = GetFirst($tabletwo);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should only make one try catch for the whole block.
You can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551668/what-are-the-best-practices-for-catching-and-re-throwing-exceptions?answertab=active#tab-top) for best practice on try catch.