# Does re-throwing an exception in PHP destroy the stack trace?

Tags: php, exception

In C#, doing the following would destroy the stack trace of an exception:

```csharp
try{
    throw new RuntimeException();
}
catch(Exception e){
    //Log error

    //Re-throw
    throw e;
}
```

Because of this, using `throw` rather than `throw e` is preferred. This will let the same exception propagate upwards, instead of wrapping it in a new one.

However, using `throw;` without specifying the exception object is invalid syntax in PHP. Does this problem simply not exist in PHP? Will using throw $e as follows not destroy the stack trace?

```
<?php

try{
    throw new RuntimeException();
}
catch(Exception $e){
    //Log error

    //Re-throw
    throw $e;
}
```

Comment: If you want to add other details or handle other exceptions, you can also wrap an exception in another exception by assigning it to the "previous" exception as the third parameter of the constructor. See here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php#exception.props.previous

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you throw $e in PHP like you did you rethrow the exisiting exception object without changing anything of its contents and send all given information including the stacktrace of the catched exception - so your second example is the correct way to rethrow an exception in PHP.

If (for whatever reason) you want to throw the new position with the last message, you have to rethrow a newly created exception object:

```
throw new RuntimeException( $e->getMessage() );
```

Note that this will not only lose the stack trace, but also all other information which may be contained in the exception object except for the message (e.g. `Code`, `File` and `Line` for `RuntimeException`). So this is generally ***not recommended***!

Comment: Why would you throw a new Exception with the message from the old Exception instead of throwing again the old exception ? What is the logic behind this approach? You should rather use Exception Chaining in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Re-throwing the same exception will not destroy the stack trace.
But depending on what you need, you might want to just throw the same exception or build an Exception Chaining ( see PHP Documentation > [Exception::__construct](http://php.net/manual/en/exception.construct.php) )

A very good explanation of when and why one would choose one approach over another is given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5551828/2162347)

Comment: In my case, we added a high-level exception handler which was basically "log and rethrow", so I just wrote `throw $t;`.  Only problem was, this swallowed the stack trace in the orange XDebug screen on localhost development.  Throwing a new exception, passing in `$t` as the previous exception, solved this issue in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.This is a best way to catch the exception and re-throw the same exception object which carries the stack-trace data. Once you reaches the point of method that handles requests, just catch it there and send response back to user accordingly.

Its a bad idea to throw a new exception object which looses the stack-trace and create an additional object causing memory load.

Hope this helps.